# eCPM value from an advertising view

Tags: admob, ads, chartboost

I use chartboost for displaying my ads. I have a campaign set to CPI(cost per install) and in my dashboard i have some graphs and stats. I know how the eCPM formula is calculated(revenue generated by a banner, divided by the number of ad impressions of that banner expressed in units of 1,000).

Now what i have in those stats is an eCMP of 0.18. I know that for a publisher this value must be as high as possible what about for an advertiser this value is really low, it is good or is not important?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible value. It depends on lots of parameters. Most of them you can't manage.
I don't know how can you improve chartboost eCPM. But you can increase eCPM for admob by using firebase. Connect your app, firebase and admob. Or use interstitial banners. They much better.

Comment: ok i see, but i don't understand the value importance as a advertiser point of view is it important for a campaign of cost per installs?